# How to update using angularFireCollection which items not exist previously

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have this parent node with `text` and I want to add a `media` into the parent node also if the `text` is changed will update as well.

```
{
 parent: {
  text: 'this is content'
 }
}
```

The `media` value from a third-party callback. How to pass it to `update()`? I tried `{media: callbackVal}` but not working.

```
$scope.parent = angularFireCollection(firebaseRef.child('parent'));
$scope.parent.update(What_to_do_here, function(error){
 //something...
});
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe my question is not clear enough.

In Firebase JS, we can do this to update or insert media into the node.

```
new Firebase(firebaseRef).update({ media: 'value'} );
```

How to do this in `angularFireCollection ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the annotated AngularFire source: http://angularfire.com/src/angularFire.html#section-38

It looks like `AngularFireCollection.update()` takes a key/item and a callback function. So you need to edit the entry you want to update directly in your AngularFireCollection, (e.g. `$scope.parent.getByName('media').value = 'alligator scrimshaw'`) and then call `$scope.parent.update($scope.parent.getByName('media'), function(err) { ... })`.

NOTE: One rather confusing thing (which maybe I am misunderstanding) is that there doesn't seem to be a way to add data to an AngularFireCollection by id. So if `media` doesn't already exist in your Firebase, `$scope.parent.getByName('media')` will return `undefined`. For this reason, if you don't need explicit syncing, and implicit syncing is fine, I would use an AngularFire object instead of an AngularFireCollection.